# Returning to previous page with search results after clicking cancel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a page with a search bar. When the user enters something to search, the page is filled with search results. When the user clicks on one of the search results rows and navigates to another page to edit information and there is a cancel button. If the user clicks the cancel button they will be returned back to the search page and they will have to enter text again to search. How can create it so that when they click cancel they will be returned to the search page but with previous search results. Many examples or information on this will be appreciated.

This is what my cancel button looks like:

```
<a class="printRemove" id="cancel" href='<%: Url.Action("Search","Office") %>'>
<img alt="" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/images/newCancel.png") %>"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your cancel button call `history.back(-1)`

OR pass values, required for search, back on cancel button and search again .

Comment: Thanks! In my View User Control i added the Javascript and it worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether your search is a GET or a POST.

If your search is a GET, using some Javascript will return your user to the search URL with the parameter he wrote:

```
history.back(-1)
```

If your search is a POST, you can use the `TempData` construct to save the search param temporarily.

Comment: Being strict, if your action is not changing something on the backend it should be a GET... not a POST.  But your response worth.

Comment: @Romias: Completely agree, but sometimes The Pointy Haired boss-man wants things done in a certain way. :)